# Aplicar Required Dependiendo de una Condición en Angular 7

Tags: html, angular

Tengo el siguiente botón

```
        <button 
        (click)="info = !info" 
        type="button" 
        class="btn btn-info"> 
        Cambiar a: <span *ngIf="info">Telefono</span> <span *ngIf="!info">Correo</span>
        </button>
```

Donde creo una variable que tomo del componente, pero quiero utilizar la variable info (que se incicializa en `true`) en el ngOnInit:

```
ngOnInit() {
this.info = false;
```

}

...Para pasarla al campo nombre y que el `Required` se aplique si es `true`, o no, si es `false`

```
<input 
                    name="primerN" 
                    [(ngModel)]="product.primerN" 
                    type="text" 
                    class="form-control"
                    placeholder="Primer Nombre"  
                    minlength="2" 
                    [required]="info"
                    pattern="[A-Za-zÑñ]+"
                    #primerN="ngModel"
                    [ngClass]="{'is-invalid':  primerN?.errors?.required  || primerN?.errors?.minlength || primerN?.errors?.pattern  , 'is-valid' : primerN?.value}"
                    >
                    <div class="invalid-feedback" *ngIf="primerN?.errors?.minlength">
                      por lo menos {{ primerN.errors.minlength.requiredLength }} caracteres
                    </div>
                    <div class="invalid-feedback" *ngIf="primerN?.errors?.pattern">
                      Solo letras [Aa-Zz]
                    </div>

        </div>
```

Cuando entra la pagina funciona bien, pero cuando doy click en el boton para que la variable info sea `false` me sale el siguiete error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Estoy utilizando validación por template de Angular

Comment: Me gustaría saber que buena practica puedo usar para que el `required` se aplique de forma dinámica

Comment: En primer lugar, no deberías asignarle un valor al atributo [`required`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Forms/Form_validation#The_required_attribute). Si un elemento de tipo `input` tiene establecido el atributo `required`, la validación proporcionada por el navegador mostrará el mensaje adecuado antes de realizar el `submit` del formulario. Creo que lo que debes hacer es añadir dicho atributo de acuerdo al valor de tu variable, en vez de asignarle el valor de tu variable al atributo. Saludos